# Reading image EXIF data from SFTP server without downloading the file

Tags: python, sftp, exif

I'm writing a script that downloads files from a SFTP server. However, there are 10k files (~5MB per file) in each folder, and I only want to download files that are, say, 12 hours apart. (eg. 12:00 time and 00:00).

But I seem to only be able to read the date for last modification, not creation. This date seems hidden until I have the file locally. I have an alternative strategy, but it is not as clean as getting the right files on the first download.

Comment: EXIF is not the only metadata which may have a "content created" date stored. There's also [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) and [IPTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Press_Telecommunications_Council#Photo_metadata), as well as file format specific metadata (JFIF, TIFF, PNG, GIF, QTFF, RIFF, PSD...).

Comment: @AmigoJack Sure, but it does not change the question. All these are part of the file *contents*, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OP reduces his question to EXIF only and might not even be aware of others, especially when EXIF was not used but his data of interest is stored nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG EXIF metadata is part of the file *contents*, not part of file metadata, as far as filesystem/FTP is concerned. So it's not a part of a directory listing, at least not with any SFTP server I know of.

You cannot retrieve it without downloading the JPEG file. Or at least not without downloading the part of the file that contains the EXIF.

---

Related question: [Check aspect ratio of image stored on an FTP server without downloading the file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67826316/850848)